# insert and exclude duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicate-data

I have 2 equal databases (A and B) with one table each running in separate offline machines.

Every day I export their data (as csv) and "merge" it into a 3rd database (C). I first process A, then B (I insert the content from A to C, then the contents from B to C)

Now, it could happen that I get duplicate rows. I consider a duplicate if some field, for example "mail" already exists. I don't care if the rest of the fields are the same.

How can I insert A and B into C excluding those rows that are duplicates?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution should be to create a unique index on the columns in question and run the second insert as INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as using `INSERT IGNORE` causes any errors to be [thrown as warnings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

This may have some side effects and may result in behavior you may not expect. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) for details on some of the side effects.

If you end up using the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, it will also provide a means of changing your logic to update specific fields with new data should business requirements change.

For instance, you can tally how many times a duplicate record was inserted by saying `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity+1`.

The post referenced above has a ton more information.